# ModalPopupExtender displays a black box when it contains a user control

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'm using the Ajax Control Toolkit's ModalPopupExtender. It works great but when I add a user control to the panel it is set to display, the modal popup is displayed with a black box over it.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Is anyone familiar with the problem? Is there a workaround?

Thanks,
Shay.

Comment: If you post some code, and perhaps a url - I will take a look for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this post:

http://forums.asp.net/p/991583/1288989.aspx

Try setting drop shadow to false and then make sure your DOCTYPE is XHTML. If that doesn't fix it then definitely post your code and I'm sure somebody can figure it out.

Comment: DropShadow="false" did it! Thanks.